# Python3 and Tcl/Tk 8.5 on OS X 10.5

Tags: python, tkinter, activepython, activetcl

On a **10.5** Mac (i386) I’ve install  ActivePython-3.1.2.3 and ActiveTcl8.5.17.0

I’ve got a trouble with my *script.py* and I guess it come from Tcl/Tk invocation.
In a terminal :

```
Python3
    import tkinter
    tkinter._test()
```

return me **8.4** version !?

How can I “link” python3 and Tcl/Tk **8.5** ?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the answer to my question but i understand something which can help:
on my above command, ***python3*** is an alias which refer to "official" *Python 3.4.3* (unfortunately "link" with Tcl/Tk **8.4**)

To call *ActivePython-3.1*, i just have to use ***python3.1*** alias, which is indeed related to Tcl/Tk **8.5**.